# How should setup.py and requirements.txt be used by app developers?

Tags: python, python-2.7, packaging, distutils

What should an *app developer* place in `setup.py` and `requirements.txt`? Should an *app* even have a `setup.py`?

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html) seem to only cover the scenario of writing a *module*. But in an app, how should package and module dependency be encoded? Using both setup.py and requirements.txt?

I've been handed a 2.7.8 project with some questionable coding, and I'm not sure if this `setup.py` is reasonable. I'm surprised by the amount of boilerplate coding:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
import sys

if sys.argv[1] == 'test':
    import multiprocessing, logging
    from billiard import util

with open('requirements.txt') as f:
    required = f.read().splitlines()

if sys.version_info < (2, 7, 0):
    required.append('importlib')

setup(
    version='0.1',
    name='...',
    description='...',
    author='...',
    author_email='...',
    packages=find_packages(),
    package_data={},
    install_requires=required,
    include_package_data=True,
    tests_require=[
        'billiard',
        'nose==1.3'
    ],
    test_suite='nose.collector'
)
```

I'm new to Python, but I see some potential problems:

- An irrelevant version number which needs to be manually updated.
- The 'test' imports aren't relevant to the project ("multiprocessing").
- We don't run tests by executing setup.py; we execute the `nosetests` command.
- `install_requires` depends on the contents of `requirements.txt`. But afaik it should be the other way around: `requirements.txt` needs to be generated based on the `install_requires` section.
- It seems to check for a python version which the app isn't coded to support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> An irrelevant version number which needs to be manually updated.

The version number in `setup.py` is only important if your application / deployment needs it.

> The 'test' imports aren't relevant to the project ("multiprocessing").

In that case you may need to remove it - it could be outdated code.

> We don't run tests by executing setup.py; we execute the nosetests command.

I'd have to look it up but some testing frameworks use `setup.py` to install the project in a separate environment (such as `tox` for testing the project in various Python interpreters).

> This depends on the contents of requirements.txt, but afaik it should be the other way around: requirements.txt needs to be generated based on an install_requires section in setup.py

The use of `requirements.txt` and `setup.py` varies across the Python community. So far, `setup.py` needs to know the requirements when installing the project but when your application is meant to be deployed, you can do without a `setup.py` file and only use a `requirements.txt` file.

> There's no install_requires.

That may be an issue, depending on whether you actually use `setup.py` to install your dependencies (as said above, it's entirely possible to develop and deploy an application without a `setup.py` file).

> It seems to check for a python version which the app isn't coded to support.

You may need to remove that then.